# Why do I have to run "webpack" command again n again?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working with a React project. Every time I make any change in any of the .js files, I have to run the "webpack" command in the terminal again to get the changes reflect on browser. Is there any way so that I cannot have to run the "webpack" command again n again.

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) and react hot loader, also you need development config. Please take a look at this page [ReactHotLoader](https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/) and if you find it complex comment here and i will provide you more links that could be helpful.

Also please take a look at this example [Github:React-redux-app](https://github.com/coryhouse/pluralsight-redux-app-used-to-build-script), this could help you set up your development env.

Comment: I have installed react-hot-loader. Now what should I do. It's complex

Comment: I have posted the problem I am facing to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278348/getting-started-with-react-hot-loader?noredirect=1#comment65891523_39278348

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just run webpack with `-w` flag to make it watch for changes and rebuild every time on change.

```
webpack -w
```